# Sort a list in Dart not the same as sorted list in Swift

Tags: swift, list, sorting, dart, flutter

I have successfully implemented a sorting algorithm in Swift for iOS.
(see code below).

Now, I would like to implement the same algo in Dart for Flutter.

And I had to realise that my trial (see below) does not do the same as the Swift code. Why ????

Can anybody explain the difference between Swift's `sorted` function and Dart's `sort` function ? Why is my below code-snippets not doing the same in Swift and Dart ???

Here is the Swift code:

```swift
return stationItems.sorted {
    let nameA = $0.name!
        .replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "", options: .literal, range: nil)
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "ä", with: "a", options: .literal, range: nil)
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "ö", with: "o", options: .literal, range: nil)
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "ü", with: "u", options: .literal, range: nil)
        .lowercased()
    let nameB = $1.name!
        .replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "", options: .literal, range: nil)
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "ä", with: "a", options: .literal, range: nil)
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "ö", with: "o", options: .literal, range: nil)
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "ü", with: "u", options: .literal, range: nil)
        .lowercased()
    let searchTermy = searchTerm
        .replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "", options: .literal, range: nil)
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "ä", with: "a", options: .literal, range: nil)
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "ö", with: "o", options: .literal, range: nil)
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "ü", with: "u", options: .literal, range: nil)
        .lowercased()

    if nameA == searchTermy && nameB != searchTermy {
        return true
    } else if nameA.hasPrefix(searchTermy) && !nameB.hasPrefix(searchTermy)  {
        return true
    } else if nameA.contains(searchTermy) && !nameB.contains(searchTermy) {
        return true
    } else {
        let n = searchTermy.count
        for i in 0..<searchTermy.count {
            if nameA.hasPrefix(String(searchTermy[..<(n-i)])) && !nameB.hasPrefix(String(searchTermy[..<(n-i)])) {
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Here is the Dart code:

```dart
return stationList.sort((a, b) {
   var nameA = a.stopName
      .replaceAll(RegExp(','), '')
      .replaceAll(RegExp('ä'), 'a')
      .replaceAll(RegExp('ö'), 'o')
      .replaceAll(RegExp('ü'), 'u')
      .toLowerCase();
   var nameB = b.stopName
      .replaceAll(RegExp(','), '')
      .replaceAll(RegExp('ä'), 'a')
      .replaceAll(RegExp('ö'), 'o')
      .replaceAll(RegExp('ü'), 'u')
      .toLowerCase();
   var searchTermy = stationName
      .replaceAll(RegExp(','), '')
      .replaceAll(RegExp('ä'), 'a')
      .replaceAll(RegExp('ö'), 'o')
      .replaceAll(RegExp('ü'), 'u')
      .toLowerCase();
   if ((nameA == searchTermy) && (nameB != searchTermy)) {
      return 1;
   } else if (nameA.startsWith(searchTermy) && !nameB.startsWith(searchTermy)) {
      return 1;
   } else if (nameA.contains(searchTermy) && !nameB.contains(searchTermy)) {
      return 1;
   } else {
      var n = searchTermy.length;
      for (int i = 0; i < searchTermy.length; i++) {
        if (nameA.startsWith(searchTermy.substring(0, (n - i))) && !nameB.startsWith(searchTermy.substring(0, (n - i)))) {
          return 1;
       } else {
          return 0;
       }
     }
     return 0;
   }
});
```

Comment: A concrete example with input and expected/actual output would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

true/false is different from 0/1 here.

Dart sort checks 3 different things.

In a comparison between `A` and `B`, we have 3 possibilities:

- The callback returns `0`. In which case `A` and `B` are equal
- The callback returns a number `> 0`. It means that `A` is placed *after* `B`
- The callback returns a number `< 0`. In which case `A` is placed *before* `B`.

Comment: Thank you, Rémi. I saw that too. But I guess, what I do not understand is why my Dart-List gets changed even if I return 0. Or in other words, why is the following muting the list, instead of leaving it as it is: `stationList.sort((a, b) { return 0; });`

Comment: That's just how `sort` works. It doesn't create a new list, it sorts the existing one. To begin with, `sort` returns nothing.

Comment: Ah, it starts making sense.... The true/false in Swift means that iterating through the list - the elements ($0 and $1) for a given iterating-moment are either `mutated in position` (if true: A is placed before B) or `kept in position` (if false).

Comment: In Dart, the `sort` works differently and iterating through the list cannot have the same two-fold decision as in Swift's `sorted` but rather requires a triple-state implementation as you described above.  `true` must translate in callback-return `< 0` I guess - and `false` must either be `0` or `> 0` or `< 0` depending on the elements at a given time in the iteration. Does this make sense ?